# How do I get only a unique value (note) to play - no repeats Javascript

Tags: javascript, unique, repeat, midi

I have a perfectly working script. Basically, I am polling an API every 5 seconds for `myJson.Temperature` and a MIDI note is played corresponding to the returned value. The values are between 0 and 16. Here is the script:

```
let easymidi = require("easymidi")
let output = new easymidi.Output("mindiPort", true)
let interval;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

let sendNote = (noteValue, duration) => {
    output.send("noteon", noteValue)

    setTimeout(()=> {
        output.send("noteoff", noteValue)
    }, duration);
}

const api_url = 'https://www.placeholder_url.com?timeout=1000'
setInterval(() =>
fetch(api_url)
   .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
   })

.then((myJson) => {
      let note;
      if (myJson.temperature == 0) {
        note = 24;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 2) {
        note = 25;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 4) {
        note = 26;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 6) {
        note = 27;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 8) {
        note = 28;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 10) {
        note = 29;
      } else if (myJson.temparature == 12) {
        note = 30;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 14) {
        note = 31;
      } else {
        note = 32;
      }
      let noteValue = {
         note: note,
         velocity: 100,
         channel: 1
       }
       sendNote(noteValue, 500)
   
 }), 5000); // API call every 5 seconds **This will also play a (same) note every five seconds
//  if conditions are met**
```

How do can I get the note to only play once ie; - if a subsequent poll is done and returns the same value, that note can be ignored until a unique value is returned? I have looked at `filter` and `onlyUnique` but I am not sure how to incorporate them into the code. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply moving your note declaration upper in scope so that, when you reassign it on a new call, you can simply do `if(myNewNote === note) return` ?

Comment: You can try to store the last temperature value outside of the interval. Every time you poll, compare the last value and if they are equal then don't do anything. If they are different, update the last value

Comment: On a side note: You can store the temperature->note mapping in an object. Then you could do smth like `note = myObj[temperature]` instead of all these `else if` statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a simple approach and keep track of last emited note:

**EDIT**: my code was wrong because it was checking against complex objects equality, fixed it

```
let easymidi = require("easymidi")
let output = new easymidi.Output("mindiPort", true)
let interval;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

let lastNote = null;
let sendNote = (noteValue, duration) => {
    output.send("noteon", noteValue)

    setTimeout(()=> {
        output.send("noteoff", noteValue)
    }, duration);
}

const api_url = 'https://www.placeholder_url.com?timeout=1000'
setInterval(() =>
fetch(api_url)
   .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
   })

.then((myJson) => {
      let note;
      if (myJson.temperature == 0) {
        note = 24;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 2) {
        note = 25;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 4) {
        note = 26;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 6) {
        note = 27;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 8) {
        note = 28;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 10) {
        note = 29;
      } else if (myJson.temparature == 12) {
        note = 30;
      } else if (myJson.temperature == 14) {
        note = 31;
      } else {
        note = 32;
      }
      if (lastNote !== note) {
          let noteValue = {
             note: note,
             velocity: 100,
             channel: 1
           }
           sendNote(noteValue, 500)
      }
      lastNote = note;
   
 }), 5000); // API call every 5 seconds **This will also play a (same) note every five seconds
//  if conditions are met**
```

Comment: Great idea here - def sends me towards the right direction! For some reason the note still repeats - not sure why, but I should be able to troubleshoot from here :) edit its actually repeating every 3 seconds or so, so it might have something else to do with the code.

Comment: damn - there is no reason why this shouldnt work. There has to be something else fundamentally wrong with my code.

Comment: my bad, I didn't see noteValue was a complex object, I'll update my code

Comment: Thank YOU Thank YOU!!! Dont apologize, your little emission taught me a lot trying to troubleshoot this. It now works - 100% I am so happy - I am much more comfortable with Python, so fixing Javascript bugs is pure headache for me. I OWE you!! :) :) :)